# Discrete mathematics statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is this statement true ?

> ∀x ∈ R, ∃y ∈ R,(x ≥ y) ⇒ (x > y)

I believe it is not because for example if x is 5 and y is 5 it satisfies "(x ≥ y)" but it doesn't mean that it is also "(x > y)".

Am I correct ? Your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mind I ask, why aren't these types of questions in the Mathematics StackExchange if they are mathematical topics with applications in CS?

Comment: Probably that's where this question belongs.  I was going to say that probably the OP is just unfamiliar with MathStackExchange, but apparently that isn't true.

Comment: I've asked 6 question on there in the past 24 hours. Didn't know there was a limit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the statement is true.

Given `x` in `R` (which I presume stands for the real numbers), let `y = x - 1`.  Then, we need to check whether `(x >= y) => (x > y)` is true.  Both the left and right sides of the implication are true (although only the right one needs to be), so we have `true => true`, which evaluates to `true` as well.

So, for any `x` you give me, I've just given you a `y` that makes the desired implication hold.

While the statement is true as written it doesn't mean what you probably think it does.

**Edit:** Interestingly, if I say, given `x`, let `y = x + 1`, then the implication statement *also* evaluates to true.  This is because then `x >= y` fails, and so does `x > y`, so we have `false => false`, which also evaluates to `true`.

For more information, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: Beat me to it, also what I believe kiasy missed was that you only have to find one y that satisfies the predicate not every y

Comment: Well thank you @andrey . I read the question wrong. There sure exists a y for any x to satisfy the conditions. How would you "prove" it though ?

Comment: I just proved it: given any `x`, let `y = x - 1` (or `x + 1` for that matter, in fact any value except `y = x` works).  Then it is easy to check (as in my answer) that the implication statement holds.

Comment: @Andrey what if the question then was "∃y ∈ R, ∀x ∈ R,(x ≥ y) ⇒ (x > y)" ?

Comment: That statement is false.  Given `y` in `R`, let `x = y`.  Then `x >= y` is `true`, but `x > y` is `false`, so the implication is `true => false`, which evaluates to false.

Comment: @Andrey and because it says that any Y should work and we proved that if x=y doesn't work then we must disagree right ?

Comment: No.  I think you are trying to parse the whole expression at once, using the usual English meanings of the words corresponding to the logical operations.  Often, this approach will not work.  Try to parse the expression one unit at a time.